# How should one use "not to mention"?

Tags: verbs

**I am confused about how to use "not to mention". Does it take to infinitive or bare infinitive?**

In the 3rd Practice Test of the Official Guide of SAT, there is the 38th question. Here I quote from the passage:

> For centuries, cats have guarded this famous museum, [ridding] it of mice, rats, and other rodents that could damage the art, not to mention 【38】scared off visitors.

The choices of this question are:

A. scared
B. scaring
C. scare
D. have scared.

The Official Guide has offered the key, which is C.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It helps the community to see the context you're working with. I've added some context based on your comments to Miztli's answer. Feel free to [edit] it to your liking.

Comment: @Cascabel *Ridding* looks fine there. It expands on what the author meant by guarding the museum.

Comment: @Cascabel Ah. :)

Comment: @Cascabel I've gotten *rid* of it as it's not germane to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in full is saying

> ...rodents that could damage the art, not to mention they [the rodents] could scare off visitors.

Thus, we see that "scare" is correct, as it is parallel to "damage".

It's a rather awkward sentence regardless though. Who writes these English sample sentences, anyways?

Comment: Indeed. Selecting (b) *scaring* would change the sense of the sentence to imply that it's the *cats* that scare off visitors. Not as plausible, but still grammatically correct. +1 for "parallel".

Answer (score 0):

Neither. It usually requires a noun and so when used with verbs it can take a gerund/present participle (i.e. an *-ing* form). Thus:

> He liked singing and acting, not to mention **playing** the bassoon!

However, a more natural phrasing might use a clause with a finite verb introduced by "that" (which is often accompanied by "the fact"):

> He sings, he dances, not to mention (the fact) that **he acts**, too!

Comment: But in the 3rd Practice Test of the Official Guide of SAT, there is the 38th question. Here I quote from the passage: "For centuries, cats have guarded this famous museum, riddling it of mice, rats, and other rodents that could damage the art, not to mention 【38】scared off visitors."

Comment: The choices of this question are: A. scared B. scaring C. scare D. have scared. The Official Guide has offered the key, which is C.

Comment: Hm, yes, it's something that can be quite dependent on context. Nevertheless, in that example, "scared" is a finite verb.
By the way, are you aware there is a separate stack exchange for second-language learners of English? Here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OG has explained that it created parallelism with "could damage". Rodents that could damage...not to mention [could] scare off...

Comment: In such cases it would indeed take a bare rather than _to_-infinitive due to ellipsis (or parallelism, as you/OG call it). Thank you for providing further examples.

Comment: In any circumstance in which an obvious fact is by default not included in the evaluation.  Imaginative use: "This car will never hit 100 mph, it only has a 20 hp engine!  Not to mention the trunk is filled with bricks!"  "Well, there's your problem..."

Comment: Your first answer is correct. It should still be the gerund in the example, *scaring*. The parallelism is between ***ridding** [the museum] of rodents* and ***scaring** off visitors*. (*Riddling*, with the letter L, is clearly a typo.)

Comment: @1006a The cats are most certainly not doing the scaring.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Why not? Cats are scary, and it's the only grammatical option. *I* would hesitate to visit a museum haunted by centuries-old feral cats.